# Spring data JPA updates one/many-to-many relationship using Beanutils.copyProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes with one-to-many relationship.

```
class Hotel {
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();
}
class Meeting {
    @Column(name = "meeting_time")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime meetingTime;

    @Column(name = "number_people")
    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    private int numberPeople;
}

class HotelDto{
    private long id;
    private List<MeetingDto> meetingDtos;
}
class MeetingDto {
    private long id;
    private LocalDateTime meetingTime;
    private int numberPeople;
}
```

To update the existing hotel in the database, do I have to retrive one by one the existing meeting from meeting database table and assign new time and number, then assign the meeting list to the hotel? If not, how do I resolve the reference exception after I copy a list through `BeanUtils.copyProperties`
e.g.

```
Hotel newHotel = new Hotel();
Hotel hotel = hotelDao.findById(hotelDto.getId());
List<Meeting> newMeetingList = new ArrayList<>();
for (MeetingDto mDto : hotelDto.getMeetingDtos()) {
    Meeting meeting = meetingDao.findById(mDto.getId());
    meeting.setMeetingTime(mDto.getMeetingTime());
    meeting.setNumberPeople(mDto.getNumberPeople());
    // meetingDao.saveAndFlush(meeting);     should I add this?
    newMeetingList.add(meeting);
}
newHotel.setMeetings(newMeetingList);
BeanUtils.copyProperties(newHotel, hotel, "id");
hotelDao.saveAndFlush(hotel);
```

Is there a better way to update the object with the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the hotel you should just load it from database, update what you want and save it

```
Hotel hotel = hotelDao.findById(hotelDto.getId());
hotel.getMeetings().add(newMeeting); 
hotelDao.saveAndFlush(hotel);
```

Comment: take a look at this https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I read it before, it only adds the item of the 'many' part, which I believe that it creates a new item instead of updating the existing item. So the newly added item has a different id.

Comment: Hotel and Meeting have an Id right? I will assume you didn't add it in entities here, but they exist in your code. In the way you mapped it, using a unidirectional OneToMany, Hotel owns the relationship. You just need to load the hotel, get the meeting that you want to update from the list and change it, that is all. Is it not working? By the way, you are not following his advice: "the bidirectional OneToMany association is the best way to map a one-to-many database relationship when we really need the collection on the parent side of the association."

Comment: I tried it, but the effect is weird: sometimes the data changes immediately after I call setter, other times it takes effect only after I save the item through dao. I also want to use `BeanUtils.copyProperties` to save my time but it does not work for collections.

Answer (score 0):

BeanUtils is a good API to use, but it does kind of shallow object mapping. It doesn't do a good job when working with the objects that contain in other objects and figuring out their data types.Use ModelMapper instead of BeanUtils.Also ModelMapper uses TypeTokens to allow mapping of generic parameterized types.  if you wonder how it works you can read the documentation from this link http://modelmapper.org/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).